# What's the principle of SPARQL `SERVICE` clause query?

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, dbpedia, linked-data

I know that `SPARQL federated query engine` (such as Jena) decomposes it into individual SPARQL based on `Service`, then sends it to the specified `SPARQL endpoint` for execution, and finally combines the query results.

I know the usage of the [SERVICE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/) clause, but I don't know its principle. Do you have any relevant articles or tutorials?

For example, I have the following SPARQL federated query statement. How does it decompose and work? Can you give me a specific SPARQL sample?

The meaning of SPARQL below is: What are the Taxons under the corresponding [Yago](https://yago-knowledge.org/sparql/query) for [dbo:Stephania](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stephania)?

```
SELECT ?yagoPlant
WHERE {
  SERVICE <https://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Stephania> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> ?yago .
  }
  SERVICE <https://yago-knowledge.org/sparql/query> {
    ?yagoPlant <https://schema.org/parentTaxon> ?yago .
    ?yagoPlant a <https://schema.org/Taxon> .
  }
}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: As fa as I know: querying multiple SPARQL endpoints in a single query.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in the query execution plan (see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/explain.html)? This is not a general principle though, the strategy can be different for individual queries.

Comment: what do you mean by "decompose"? in your current query, each SERVICE request is invoked on the corresponding SPARQL endpoint -  that is the only requirement by definition. And then, indeed the "other" SPARQL evaluation. In the end, the SERVICE is just another group graph pattern when it comes to evaluation semantics.

Comment: Indeed, just executing both request independently could by highly expensive as it can tend to get lots of data aka bindings. That's why implementations also try to inline some variable bindings if allowed and possible w.r.t. scoping such that you only gather data from a SERVICE that is related to the already evaluated bindings.